# Sendind POST notifications from ipad

Tags: objective-c, ipad, apple-push-notifications

I've developed a chat that uses APNS in order to send the messages to the logged users.

For this I've used MoonAPNS dll in c#, and I've developed an ASP web service to store in database and send the notifications.

I've tested every method in the server, directly connecting from IE. And works fine. All data is stored in DB and the notifications are properly sended to registered devices.

The implementation in objective-c in order to be used from devices, works fine. The service is called and every step in DB is executed, same as in the test from IE. Excepts the notifications are not being received in devices.

Anyone knows if there is any problem when the service is called from devices?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Holly Mother!

Finally I found the problem.

MoonAPNS dll allows to add extra labels with info in the notification body.

I've been using this feature in order to add extra info of the user, in order to be consumed when the notification is received.

Yesterday one of the last changes I did is to add an icon URL as user label. This URL was injected in the notification as a extra field.

Well, as Murphy law says... Once I've removed this last minute change, everything worked fine.

Now the question is: APNS blocks messages with embbeded URL as field?

Thanks.